# MacOS programming C delivers error: zsh: segmentation fault

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault

As described in the heading, the terminal delivers the error: zsh: segmentation fault. Here is the - pretty basic - code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int age = 0;
    printf("Input your age!");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf(age);
}
```

thanks for the help solving this problem :)

Comment: `printf(age);` --> `printf("%d\n", age);`. Compile with warnings: `clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -o program program.c`

Comment: `printf()` requires a format string, which you have not provided.

Comment: Also, turn up the warning level of your compiler, and pay attention to the warnings it emits.  It ought to be warning you (at least) that the data type of `age` is not correct for the first argument to `printf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> printf(age);

should be `printf("%d", age);`

You need to pass in a string literal (eg: "hello world") with a format specifier (exactly the same way you did it in `scanf`) and then pass the age (not its address as you did with `scanf`, so without the &) as a second argument.
for example

```
printf("I am %d years old\n", age);
```

For the above example, I printed a message that writes "I am [age] years old" and then continues down to a new line (that's the '\n'). The '%d' is a format specifier; what it does is it specifies that in its position, the function should print a value of a specific type (%d specifies an integer). You can have multiple of these specifiers and it prints the arguments you give it in linear order. I would highly recommend you look at [this[1]](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), it should explain it better than I can.

Comment: That's a good and detailed explanation worth an up vote.

Comment: @XinCheng Thank you! I've used SO for years and decided to help, so I'm glad I am actually able to help peeps and answer properly.